# Access Smartphone from PC with defect screen

Tags: usb-debugging, broken-screen

After I dropped my Google Pixel 3a the screen just stays black. However when I connect it to my Laptop I can see in the hardware manager that an "MPT media device" is connected.

Is there any way to unlock my smartphone in order to transfer files?

Comment: What lock screen do you use? Pattern, PIN or password?

Comment: @Robert I am using a PIN

Comment: A PIN is good because then you can unlock your phone using a simple USB keyboard attached via USB OTG.